# png file cannot be opened

Tags: png, file-format

I am working as a software developer, where users can upload images for further processing. Someone uploaded this png File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aonvttrobrrkpcb/Error_Image.png?dl=0
and it crashed my software. I downloaded the file and found that no program could display the file apart from Adobe Illustrator.

Since I do not have extensive knowledge on the internals of images I just want to know what is going on with this file and why it seems to widely unsupported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a PDF, not a PNG.  Also it contains vector graphics, not raster graphics. Someone appears to have changed the file extension. Just change the file extension back to .pdf, and it will open in Adobe Reader.

Comment: +1 for daring to open it :)

Comment: @Tetsujin  I didn't actually open the file. I examined the code in a text editor to find out what it was.  I guess I'm not that brave! LOL